# How to handle "Property 'myOptionalKey' is optional in type 'myObject' but required in type '{...}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

### Problem

I'm making sortable a table with a sample table component from Material-UI. When I added optional key in `Data`, it shows an error. I guess type definition in `getComparator` doesn't expect `undefined` key, and it could be handled it with `NonNullable<...>`, but I'm not sure how to.

```js
interface Data {
  calories: number;
  carbs: number;
  fat: number;
  name: string;
  protein: number;
  age?: number;  // This is the only line I added.
}
```

### What I expect

Sort works even for `undefined` key (at least doesn't crash). It's okay nothing happens for undefined key.

### What happens now

Property 'age' is optional in type 'Data' but required in type '{ calories: string | number; carbs: string | number; fat: string | number; name: string | number; protein: string | number; age: string | number; }'

### Code

I show full source code below, but it is almost the same as found in Material-UI Sandbox, which is shown at the bottom, except one line.

```js
import React from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import {
  createStyles,
  lighten,
  makeStyles,
  Theme
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TablePagination from "@material-ui/core/TablePagination";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import TableSortLabel from "@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import FilterListIcon from "@material-ui/icons/FilterList";

interface Data {
  calories: number;
  carbs: number;
  fat: number;
  name: string;
  protein: number;
  age?: number;  // This is the only line I added.
}

function createData(
  name: string,
  calories: number,
  fat: number,
  carbs: number,
  protein: number
): Data {
  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData("Cupcake", 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData("Donut", 452, 25.0, 51, 4.9),
  createData("Eclair", 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData("Frozen yoghurt", 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
  createData("Honeycomb", 408, 3.2, 87, 6.5),
  createData("Ice cream sandwich", 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData("Jelly Bean", 375, 0.0, 94, 0.0),
  createData("KitKat", 518, 26.0, 65, 7.0),
  createData("Lollipop", 392, 0.2, 98, 0.0),
  createData("Marshmallow", 318, 0, 81, 2.0),
  createData("Nougat", 360, 19.0, 9, 37.0),
  createData("Oreo", 437, 18.0, 63, 4.0)
];

function descendingComparator<T>(a: T, b: T, orderBy: keyof T) {
  if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

type Order = "asc" | "desc";

function getComparator<Key extends keyof any>(
  order: Order,
  orderBy: Key
): (
  a: { [key in Key]: number | string },
  b: { [key in Key]: number | string }
) => number {
  return order === "desc"
    ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
    : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
}

function stableSort<T>(array: T[], comparator: (a: T, b: T) => number) {
  const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index] as [T, number]);
  stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
    const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
    if (order !== 0) return order;
    return a[1] - b[1];
  });
  return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
}

interface HeadCell {
  disablePadding: boolean;
  id: keyof Data;
  label: string;
  numeric: boolean;
}

const headCells: HeadCell[] = [
  {
    id: "name",
    numeric: false,
    disablePadding: true,
    label: "Dessert (100g serving)"
  },
  { id: "calories", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Calories" },
  { id: "fat", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Fat (g)" },
  { id: "carbs", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Carbs (g)" },
  { id: "protein", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Protein (g)" }
];

interface EnhancedTableProps {
  classes: ReturnType<typeof useStyles>;
  numSelected: number;
  onRequestSort: (
    event: React.MouseEvent<unknown>,
    property: keyof Data
  ) => void;
  onSelectAllClick: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  order: Order;
  orderBy: string;
  rowCount: number;
}

function EnhancedTableHead(props: EnhancedTableProps) {
  const {
    classes,
    onSelectAllClick,
    order,
    orderBy,
    numSelected,
    rowCount,
    onRequestSort
  } = props;
  const createSortHandler = (property: keyof Data) => (
    event: React.MouseEvent<unknown>
  ) => {
    onRequestSort(event, property);
  };

  return (
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell padding="checkbox">
          <Checkbox
            indeterminate={numSelected > 0 && numSelected < rowCount}
            checked={rowCount > 0 && numSelected === rowCount}
            onChange={onSelectAllClick}
            inputProps={{ "aria-label": "select all desserts" }}
          />
        </TableCell>
        {headCells.map((headCell) => (
          <TableCell
            key={headCell.id}
            align={headCell.numeric ? "right" : "left"}
            padding={headCell.disablePadding ? "none" : "default"}
            sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}
          >
            <TableSortLabel
              active={orderBy === headCell.id}
              direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : "asc"}
              onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
            >
              {headCell.label}
              {orderBy === headCell.id ? (
                <span className={classes.visuallyHidden}>
                  {order === "desc" ? "sorted descending" : "sorted ascending"}
                </span>
              ) : null}
            </TableSortLabel>
          </TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
  );
}

const useToolbarStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      paddingLeft: theme.spacing(2),
      paddingRight: theme.spacing(1)
    },
    highlight:
      theme.palette.type === "light"
        ? {
            color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
            backgroundColor: lighten(theme.palette.secondary.light, 0.85)
          }
        : {
            color: theme.palette.text.primary,
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.dark
          },
    title: {
      flex: "1 1 100%"
    }
  })
);

interface EnhancedTableToolbarProps {
  numSelected: number;
}

const EnhancedTableToolbar = (props: EnhancedTableToolbarProps) => {
  const classes = useToolbarStyles();
  const { numSelected } = props;

  return (
    <Toolbar
      className={clsx(classes.root, {
        [classes.highlight]: numSelected > 0
      })}
    >
      {numSelected > 0 ? (
        <Typography
          className={classes.title}
          color="inherit"
          variant="subtitle1"
          component="div"
        >
          {numSelected} selected
        </Typography>
      ) : (
        <Typography
          className={classes.title}
          variant="h6"
          id="tableTitle"
          component="div"
        >
          Nutrition
        </Typography>
      )}
      {numSelected > 0 ? (
        <Tooltip title="Delete">
          <IconButton aria-label="delete">
            <DeleteIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
      ) : (
        <Tooltip title="Filter list">
          <IconButton aria-label="filter list">
            <FilterListIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
      )}
    </Toolbar>
  );
};

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      width: "100%"
    },
    paper: {
      width: "100%",
      marginBottom: theme.spacing(2)
    },
    table: {
      minWidth: 750
    },
    visuallyHidden: {
      border: 0,
      clip: "rect(0 0 0 0)",
      height: 1,
      margin: -1,
      overflow: "hidden",
      padding: 0,
      position: "absolute",
      top: 20,
      width: 1
    }
  })
);

export default function EnhancedTable() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [order, setOrder] = React.useState<Order>("asc");
  const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = React.useState<keyof Data>("calories");
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
  const [dense, setDense] = React.useState(false);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(5);

  const handleRequestSort = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<unknown>,
    property: keyof Data
  ) => {
    const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === "asc";
    setOrder(isAsc ? "desc" : "asc");
    setOrderBy(property);
  };

  const handleSelectAllClick = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      const newSelecteds = rows.map((n) => n.name);
      setSelected(newSelecteds);
      return;
    }
    setSelected([]);
  };

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<unknown>, name: string) => {
    const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(name);
    let newSelected: string[] = [];

    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, name);
    } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(
        selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1)
      );
    }

    setSelected(newSelected);
  };

  const handleChangePage = (event: unknown, newPage: number) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
    setPage(0);
  };

  const handleChangeDense = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setDense(event.target.checked);
  };

  const isSelected = (name: string) => selected.indexOf(name) !== -1;

  const emptyRows =
    rowsPerPage - Math.min(rowsPerPage, rows.length - page * rowsPerPage);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <EnhancedTableToolbar numSelected={selected.length} />
        <TableContainer>
          <Table
            className={classes.table}
            aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
            size={dense ? "small" : "medium"}
            aria-label="enhanced table"
          >
            <EnhancedTableHead
              classes={classes}
              numSelected={selected.length}
              order={order}
              orderBy={orderBy}
              onSelectAllClick={handleSelectAllClick}
              onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
              rowCount={rows.length}
            />
            <TableBody>
              {stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                .map((row, index) => {
                  const isItemSelected = isSelected(row.name);
                  const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;

                  return (
                    <TableRow
                      hover
                      onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, row.name)}
                      role="checkbox"
                      aria-checked={isItemSelected}
                      tabIndex={-1}
                      key={row.name}
                      selected={isItemSelected}
                    >
                      <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                        <Checkbox
                          checked={isItemSelected}
                          inputProps={{ "aria-labelledby": labelId }}
                        />
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell
                        component="th"
                        id={labelId}
                        scope="row"
                        padding="none"
                      >
                        {row.name}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  );
                })}
              {emptyRows > 0 && (
                <TableRow style={{ height: (dense ? 33 : 53) * emptyRows }}>
                  <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                </TableRow>
              )}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        <TablePagination
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
          component="div"
          count={rows.length}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          page={page}
          onChangePage={handleChangePage}
          onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
      </Paper>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<Switch checked={dense} onChange={handleChangeDense} />}
        label="Dense padding"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code sandbox for Material-UI Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/8uyys)

Comment: One solution is to make age required and fill it with fake value whenever you don't need it

Comment: Thank you. I thought that at first, but I could lead a bug in other places.

Answer (score 0):

By setting all params can be optional, it works. This typing isn't so strict, but it can be one of workarounds.

```js
function getComparator<Key extends keyof any>(
  order: Order,
  orderBy: Key
): (
  a: { [key in Key]?: number | string },
  b: { [key in Key]?: number | string }
) => number {
  return order === "desc"
    ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
    : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
}
```